# Making simple UI change animations. Pop-ups sliding from the edge of the screen

Tags: android, user-interface, android-animation

The questions are quite FAQ-type, but I can't find any suitable tutorial and don't even know what exactly to search for

1) I've got a list filled with linearLayouts and need to set an animation for elements added to those layouts as shown on image. The animation is the element slides from under the existing layout elements. If an element is removed, the animation is the same reversed

[image: Pic 1]

2) There is a screen filled with elements. Tapping, for example, a certain button, you call a pop-up, which comes from the edge of the screen and is above the rest of the elements.
If you tap anywhere, except the pop-up,
a) it will slide back
b) you will interact with the objects which the pop-up does not cover

[image: Pic 2]

What makes such effects possible? How to implement them and *what to read about*?

Answer (score 0):

For 1) Setting `animateLayoutChanges=true` for LinearLayout should do the job

For 2) You can open a `Dialog` on button click and customise the animations for the dialog by calling `dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations('id of animation xml')`

Comment: For 1: how to set this value in code? LinearLayouts are not defined in XML

Comment: You can use `linearLayout.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition())` to achieve the same effect programmatically

Comment: For 2: okay. And if I do not want the popup to close at a tap around it and leave the rest of screen interactable, what then? (This was not mentioned)

Comment: You can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` for that . Also it would be really bad UX if you try to have interactions on the rest of the screen since the elements under the dialog wont be interactive and the other elements on screen are essentialy siblings of these elements. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say..